# Excel VBA Macros to copy and paste cell value to certain cells based on text in column

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am attempting to copy and paste text values to a certain amount of cells in excel based on a text comparison.

Please see below for explanation:

I have 2 column A(blank) and B(with values)

[image]

After the macros, this will be the end results:

[image]

It is basically taking the bottom cell after it detect the fruits column and pasting the cell value into row A. Note that after it reaches the next cell fruits it take the next (bottom) cell value. F123,F124 etc..

Can someone please provide me with the excel vba codes to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use VBA for this problem.  I would type:

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(B2,1)="F",B2<>"Fruits"),B2,A1)
```

into A2 and copy down.  This seems to give the effect you seek.

If you really want to use VBA, the tested code is:

```
Dim CellValue As String
Dim RowCrnt As Integer
Dim RowMax As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
  RowMax = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  For RowCrnt = 2 To RowMax
    CellValue = .Cells(RowCrnt, 2).Value
    If Left(CellValue, 1) = "F" And CellValue <> "Fruits" Then
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = CellValue
    Else
      .Cells(RowCrnt, 1).Value = .Cells(RowCrnt - 1, 1).Value
    End If
  Next
End With
```

The following explains those aspects of the above code that may be obscure to a newbie.

The macro recorder almost always uses Range("A5") or Range("A5:C10") to refer to ranges.

There appear to be a few commands (sorry, don't remember which) for which this format is compulsory but for most purposes Cells(Row, Column) is more convenient.

If you want to add 1 to every numeric value in the range "A5:C10" of sheet "Sheet1", the following shows how to do this with Cells:

```
Dim CellValue as String
Dim ColCrnt As Integer
Dim RowCrnt As Integer

With Sheets("Sheet1")
  For RowCrnt = 5 to 10
    For ColCrnt = 1 to 3    ' "A" to "C"
      CellValue = .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value
      If IsNumeric(CellValue) Then
        .Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = CellValue + 1           
      End If
    Next
  Next
End With
```

There is a time penalty with accessing cells in a worksheet but I have used CellValue more because code can get very cluttered with too many cell references.

Note: in "A5" the column comes first but in Cells(5,1) the row comes first.

You can define ranges with Cells.  The following sets "A5:C10" of the active sheet to bold:

```
Range(Cells(5,1), Cells(10,3)).Font.Bold = True
```

To address column A of the last row of the active sheet:

```
Cells(Rows.Count,"A")
```

To address the last column of row 1:

```
Cells(1,Columns.Count)
```

Ctrl+Up, Ctrl+Down, Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right can be used to jump from an empty cell to the next cell with a value in the indicated direction.  You can do the same in VBA.  But more usefully you can get the value of the row or column to which the cursor would jump without the time penalty of moving the cursor.

If the cursor was in column B of the last row and you pressed Ctrl+Up, the cursor would jump to the last row with a value in column B.  The following sets RowMax to that row number for the active sheet:

```
RowMax = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

To get the last used column of row 27:

```
ColMax = Cells(27,Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
```

Comment: nice one (of course a formula would probably be better). You owe the +1 (but you should then define the `RowMax` with an `End(xlUp^)` to desserve it :))

Comment: Hi, I tried running your codes but nothing happened. Is there something I did wrongly? I created a button and assigned the macros to it.

Comment: Thanks Tony. Worked greatly. Would be good if you added in comments to explain to first timer like me.

Comment: @Dane. Hope I have added enough explanation to be helpful without blinding you with the detail.  We have added more comments than Stack Overflow likes.  I have deleted most of mine.  I suggest you add a comment to say if I have level of detail correct and delete your earlier ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try My Macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim My_st$
Dim Ro%, Lr%

With Sheets("Sheet1")   ' Replace Sheet1 by the name of your sheet
  Lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  Range("a2").Resize(Lr).ClearContents
    For Ro = 2 To Lr
       My_st = .Cells(Ro, 2).Value
       .Cells(Ro, 1) = _
       IIf(My_st Like "[A-Z]#*", My_st, .Cells(Ro - 1, 1))
    Next
End With
End Sub
```